# How avoid multiple POST as complete request information comes in network tab of browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, bots

We have a form, if a person fills that form, we are hitting POST API.

When user submits the form, complete INFO of API (request url, headers) is visible, I was thinking if someone starts hitting this POST API through server side code, our tables would be filled with junk values?

How can we avoid this bulk data entering the system through API being directly hit by C# client, POSTMAN or any other server side clients?

Comment: Just throttle requests by IP, like only do something with 1 response every minute for each distinct IP, and even block them for an hour (day?  week?  eternity?)  if they try to do too many.  If someone's trying to spam posts then they won't realise it's having no effect.  This it the approach I always take to spam and security.  Let them think it's working, but make sure it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a really open ended question, but I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you ask (detect with certainty if a request originates from a browser or not), nor should you if it were possible - users may have a legitimate reason to use something other than a browser, or someone might want to integrate your API into a larger process, etc.

You should handle this via authentication - require the user to be authenticated with your API, then if they misbehave you can disable their user accounts (either manually or automatically with some sort of abuse detection).

Answer (score 0):

There are times when authentication is not possible or desirable for a web form. At those times a I have used a key generated on the server that I embed in the form.

The form sends back the key along with the rest of the data and you can then make any decisions you need to make based on the key. Like limiting the rate of submissions, allowing only one submission and then expiring the key, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use a captcha: a challenge is presented to the user to prove being a human, usually an image that contains some garbled text is shown to the person filling the form and (s)he is required to transcribe the text content of the image in the form. If the captcha solution is wrong or missing that POST request to the API will be discarded.

Many types of challenges are commonly used such as audio/visual/logic/mini-puzzles. You can also customize your challenge in a way that fits best with your form. For example Google provides ReCaptcha, a captcha service with js and server api.

This helps you prevent or mitigate bots, as the captcha is a challenge that is very hard for computers but easy for humans.

Using one-time captcha tokens also prevents the replay attacks you are worried about. Also, checking that the ip that received the challenge and the ip resolving it are same helps mitigate other tricks.

This still leaves room for a determined human to spam your form. So you should also keep track of the number of submissions and throttle them by ip.

Comment: Then the hackers set up a free site with desirable content (use your imagination as to what kind of content might attract droves of people) and make the visitors answer the captcha challenges! Then they have your site again.

Comment: @Enke that server would have to act as a proxy and it will be throttled/blocked because it is still a single ip. Captcha scripts usually check if the ip that calls the page is the same that downloaded the captcha image. Instead of spending money on setting up a web server with *desiderable* content, they could easily use it on one of the many available captcha solving platform, who expose easy to use APIs to hackers.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't see why they couldn't they make it so that the POSTS occur directly from the user's web page? Your point about captcha solving APIs is a good one. I had never heard of desiderable before!

Comment: @ErikE How would they get the captcha token/challenge? If the server gets it from the legit page then it is the same case because it is the server ip that will have to submit the solution. Also, this is [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) territory.

Comment: Fair enough, I just think that there could be some scenarios where this technique could work. Obviously it's not a highway down which to drive huge fleets.